# What does the 'Special Feature' teddy bear sticker mean on some games for Sears/Atari 2600?

Tags: atari-2600

I recently found some games and a system in a closet  in my folks house.  Two of them, Warlords and Defender, have a white sticker on the back with the head (I assume) of a teddy bear, that says "special feature."

I can't find any info on these, anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Are these harder to find then regular versions?

Answer (score 6):

The teddy bear sticker:

[image]

This indicates that the game contains special modes to help younger children get more enjoyment out of the game.

From the [Warlords manual](https://atariage.com/manual_html_page.php?SoftwareLabelID=593):

> CHILDREN'S VERSIONS
>
> GAMES 21, 22, and 23 are special versions for young children.  The
>   game play is slowed down considerably.  All three games feature
>   ricochet(rather than CATCH), and all three have fireballs(slow balls).
>   The only difference in the three games is the number of players(4, 3,
>   or 2).  Check the GAME SELECT MATRIX.

Atari did this with several other games including Berserk, Missile Command, Asteroids, and Yars' Revenge/Return.